# The <div> HTML element not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple webpage with some links to a few other pages at the top right of the page. I've managed to place the links correctly but then I noticed that the links weren't within the div block as I expected them to be. This is how the webpage looks now

[image: webpage pic1]

If you take a look at my css code, you will see that I have given a white bottom border to my div element but all you can see is a white line at the top(above unordered list), meaning my unordered list items that are supposed to be within the div element are instead outside it. I realized that this was because of the `float: right` property from the `links_header` class. On removing it, I got the desired behavior from the div element.

[image: webpage pic2]

My question is this. **How did the float property affect the div element** and **How can I place my ordered list items on the right side and achieve my desired look?**
I'm very new to HTML and CSS so forgive me if I made a mistake anywhere.

```css
body
{
    background-color: #171717;
}

.links_header
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.links_list
{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:25px;
}

ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.links
{
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Verdana", "Arial";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.links:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: #171717;
}
```

```html
<div class="links_header">
    <ul class="links_list">
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Certifications & Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using ```flexbox``` instead of float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.links_header`

```css
body
{
    background-color: #171717;
}

.links_header
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.links_list
{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:25px;
}

ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.links
{
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Verdana", "Arial";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.links:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: #171717;
}
```

```html
<div class="links_header">
    <ul class="links_list">
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Certifications & Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. I think I understand now why I encountered that problem.